# Iterate through Python dictionary in customer order - Per row instead of per key

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, iteration

Let's say the following situation: I have a dictionary with 3 keys. Every key is a pd dataframe with 5 rows.

I am currently iterating through the complete dictionary using:

```
for key in dict1:
    for i in range(len(dict1[key])):
         do_something
```

**So the way this iteration works is:**

1. Iterate row 1 - key 1
2. Iterate row 2 - key 1
3. Iterate row 3 - key 1
4. Iterate row 4 - key 1
5. Iterate row 5 - key 1
6. Iterate row 1 - key 2
7. Iterate row 2 - key 2
   etc
   ...

**However, what I would like to do is:**

1. Iterate row 1 - key 1
2. Iterate row 1 - key 2
3. Iterate row 1 - key 3
4. Iterate row 2 - key 1
5. Iterate row 2 - key 2
   etc
   ...

Is there a smart way to change the order in which the for loop iterates?

Comment: Can you provide a sample dictionary?

Comment: @ScottBoston I added a sample of the dict!

Comment: `pandas` doesn't have functions to work with few dataframes at the same time. Maybe you should use soenting like `zip(df1, df2, df3)` to get all first rows , next all second rows, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't need smart way. You have to use `for`-loops in different order - first `range`, next `keys`. That's all.

```
for i in range(len(dict1['key1'])):
    for key in dict1:
        print(dict1[key].iloc[i,0])
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
    'key1': pd.DataFrame([f'row{i} key1' for i in range(1, 6)]),
    'key2': pd.DataFrame([f'row{i} key2' for i in range(1, 6)]),
    'key3': pd.DataFrame([f'row{i} key3' for i in range(1, 6)]),
}

for i in range(len(dict1['key1'])):
    for key in dict1:
        print(dict1[key].iloc[i,0])
```

Result:

```
row1 key1
row1 key2
row1 key3
row2 key1
row2 key2
row2 key3
row3 key1
row3 key2
row3 key3
row4 key1
row4 key2
row4 key3
row5 key1
row5 key2
row5 key3
```

Comment: but how would you then work with multiple keys. I agree your solution works for 'key2', but what about 'for key in keys'? Then it's referenced before it's assigned..

Comment: I don't understand you question - my code works with multiple keys - with all keys in dictionary `key1, key2, key3`. If it would have more keys then it would work with more keys.

Comment: this stupidly took me 2 days to wrap my mind around. The issue was that all my keys have a different length and it kept giving me IndexErrors. So I built a try -> except IndexError in and it is all good now. Thanks man.